# c# - index of array entries inside another array using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, substring

I have an array of strings:

```
string[] stringArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "ccc", "ddd"};
```

I would like to get all indexes of this array where a substring of these strings are inside another array:

```
string[] searchArray = {"a","b"};
```

The answer I would like to get is then:

```
index = {0,1,3};
```

A soultion for just one entry of the searchArray would be:

```
List<int> index = stringArray.Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
            .Where(t => t.s.Contains(searchArray[1]))
            .Select(t => t.i)
            .ToList();
```

A solution for all entries would be:

```
List<int> index = new List<int>();
foreach (string str in searchArray)
            index.AddRange(stringArray.Select((s, i) => new { i, s })
            .Where(t => t.s.Contains(str))
            .Select(t => t.i)
            .ToList());
index.Sort();
```

But out of curiosity, are there any solutions by just using one command in LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, you just need `Any` to see if "any" of the target strings are contained in the array element:

```
List<int> index = stringArray
    .Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index })
    .Where(pair => searchArray.Any(target => pair.Value.Contains(target)))
    .Select(pair => pair.Index)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Whould this code work? Yes, Would I do it this way? No

Comment: @Eser: Without saying what you don't like about it, that isn't terribly useful. What's the problem? What's your better solution?

Comment: It is an O(n*n) algorithm. ( If we include `value.Contains(target)`  O(n**3)). Here is too late for now, but i'll think of one...

Comment: @Eser: Given that each element of one array needs to be checked against each element of another, and you can't use hashing to make it O(n+m) because it's a contains condition, not equality, I don't see how you can avoid it being O(n * m) checks. I wouldn't claim that it's not how you'd do it without having at least *some* reasonably clear idea how you *would* do it. I'd also point out that there's no indication that the OP will actually have large amounts of data. Even if there were a more efficient approach, it would almost certainly be more complex. Premature optimization and all that...

Comment: I am only also not sure about it but I would try to use some like https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-stempel/org/egothor/stemmer/Trie.html by preprosessing in a linear time. ( BTW: You updated your comment, and invalidated this :( )

Comment: @Eser: That sounds like a *huge* amount of overkill when there is no evidence in the question that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: @Skeet: Thank you! By the way your code is more readable than mine by using meaningful variable names.